# Explicitly Calculating the Cohomology of $n$-simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

My algebraic topology lecturer has set me what I think is a tough exercise in persistence. I am meant to calculate the cohomologies of an $n$-simplex, $\Delta[n]$ which I know is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $H^0(\Delta[n], \mathbb{Z})$ and trivial otherwise. I am aware that I can use contractibility and hence deduce that these cohomologies are the same as for a single point.

However, in this exercise I am barred from using any sort of topological methods; only algebraic tools are allowed. I have managed to compute $H^0(\Delta[n], \mathbb{Z})$ through coming up with explicit matrices and then finding the kernel, however I am quite stumped for higher dimensions. I was thinking of trying to come up with a short exact sequence and then using Mayer-Vietoris, or trying an inductive argument, i.e. assuming that the $k$-th cohomology is trivial and then showing that the $(k + 1)$-th cohomology is trivial as well. This is as far as I have gotten in the problem, I can't quite see how I can get a solution from these methods, so any hints would be much appreciated.